# Crystal report shows error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have created exe using Visual studio 2008. Which includes crystal report.
When i install that exe in my machine it works correct.

But, when i install that exe on other machine which does not contain visual studio  & click on Show report , my application shows errors & close.
please help me,  Thanx for advices in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to install crystal report viewer before you install the exe file
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29774